# Magento catalog index.php/admin/catalog_product/ page displays blank

Tags: admin, grid, exception

When I log into the backend and navigate to Catalogue > Manage Product everything is working fine. When I click on a product I get a blank page, with a link to 'Create new video' and 'Add an attribute'.

Our setup is: ubuntu 12.04, nginx php5-fpm and varnish.

My nginx log is displaying this error:

> *6711 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function __toString() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/app/Mage.php on line 859" while
>   reading response header from upstream, client: 82.71.243.141, server:
>   www.example.com, request: "GET
>   /index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/801/key/918d6b60004194117d8783613d066922/
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock:",
>   host: "www.example.com", referrer:
>   "https://www.example.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/bcc1f51a9f74e1f425be8d93903f0949/"

Can anyone help with problem as I'm really stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem! This issue is caused by the `Magento Product Video Gallery Extension` from `Iceberg Commerce`. The extension has a feed which offers suggested videos. The feed is not resolving which causes the error.

I basically `Disabled 'Feed Suggestions'` in:

```
Configuration > Iceberg Commerce > Video Gallery.
```

This issue is also reported [here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70022/random-magento-admin-tostring-fatal-error?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears when logging is done in wrong way.

```
Mage::logException("logging message");
```

This line will produce

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function __toString() on string in /var/www/monoqi_b2c/app/Mage.php on line 858

Probably you have some custom extension that does not process Exceptions properly.

Something is wrong with yours php error reporting, because php should report that method `logException` gets wrong type variable.

**Update**

Tried to reproduce on php cli and mod apache and I've got

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Mage::logException() must be an instance of Exception, string is given
```

Yours php Fast CGI does not support Type Hinting.

Comment: Thank you. I'm investigation your suggestion and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the *Magento Product Video Gallery Extension* from *Iceberg Commerce*.

Basically the suggested videos isn't working correctly. (Iceberg Commerce is useless for support btw)

My temporary solution, go into your `config-> iceberg commerce -> video gallery` and disable `feed suggestions`.

This fixed it immediately.